# Move two columns into one column matching on the row Column name

Tags: sql-server

Column names are in DbFieldName, I want to display, CandidateName and Positionapplied under the InPutFields where each column name matches the column value under DbFieldName

I have tried sub-queries, Joins and using the column name as a string in the select.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   135                 INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,4                   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,1                   BIT  NOT NULL
  ,CandidateName       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
  ,Character           VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
  ,CharacterReference  VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,Candidate_Details   VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL
  ,NULL                VARCHAR(4)
  ,Rachel_Anne_Cameron VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,Junior_Web_Dev      VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(135,4,1,CandidateName,Character,CharacterReference,Candidate_Details,NULL,Rachel_Anne_Cameron,Junior_Web_Dev) VALUES (136,4,1,'Positionapplied','Character','Character-Reference','Candidate Details',NULL,'Rachel Smith','Accountant');
```

I end up with the DbFieldName displaying under the InPutFields instead of the CandidateName and Positionapplied values.

Comment: Your table definition makes no sense. There are values mixed in with the column definitions? Please correct this and provide an example of the expected result and I/we will help if we can.

Comment: |Name|Address|
|David|Glasgow|
To
|Field|Field_Output|
|Name|David

Comment: |Name|Address|
|David|Glasgow|
To
|Field|Field_Output|
|Name|David|
|Address|Glasgow|

Hope that makes sense
SELECT Field, (SELECT Field FROM Table t ON t.ID = Id) 

Which should output on each row as it runs down the table columns:
SELECT Field, Name
SELECT Field, Address